# Linq return 2D array with index from string splitting

Tags: c#, linq

I have a folder with multiple files with format `NameIndex.Index`. I need a 2D array returned with Linq, where Name is my string and the two indices (both only 1 char) are the 2D array indices.

Example: Head4.2 will be in my returned array on the [4,2] position.

```
File[,] files = arrayWithAllFiles.Select(f => f.name.StartsWith(partName))
        . // dont know how to continue

/*
result would look like, where the element is the File (not it's name):
| Head0.0    Head0.1   Head0.2 ... |
| Head1.0    Head1.1   Head1.2 ... |
*/
```

PS: could it be also done to check for indices bigger than 9?

Comment: How do you intend to create the files? do you plan to create 2 files one with "4" and one with "2" as the names?

Comment: I just need them sorted in a 2D array. I'd like to cycle over the second indices. I have a character creator where the avatar is an animation. Headx.y represents a head avatar (x type of head selected, y frame of animation). I would cycle vertically in the array to play the animation for that head. If the player chooses the next Head type, the cycle would just increase or decrease x, then cycle the y index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex to parse the file names, that way you don't have to worry about the numbers being bigger than 9. The numbers can have more than one digit.
For example,

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
/*
Pattern below means - one or more non-digit characters, then one or more digits,
then a period, then one or more digits. Each segment inside the parentheses will be one
item in the split array.
*/
string pattern = @"^(\D+)(\d+)\.(\d+)$";
string name = "Head12.34";
var words = Regex.Split(name, pattern);
// Now words is an array of strings - ["Head", "12", "34"]
```

So for your example you could try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"^(\D+)(\d+)\.(\d+)$";

var indices = files.Select(f =>
    Regex.Split(f.name, pattern).Skip(1).Select(w => System.Convert.ToInt32(w)).ToArray()).ToArray();
// Getting the max indices in each direction. This decides the dimensions of the array.
int iMax = indices.Select(p => p[0]).Max();
int jMax = indices.Select(p => p[1]).Max();
var pairs = Enumerable.Zip(indices, files, (index, file) => (index, file));

File[,] files = new File[iMax + 1, jMax + 1];
foreach (var pair in pairs){
    files[pair.index[0], pair.index[1]] = pair.file;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Could you please edit it to return an array of type File (the F.name would be the string for the name)? I'll edit my question to clear up my question.

Comment: I had misunderstood the question the first time. I just edited the answer to match your updated description.

Comment: Your pattern is incorrect. You need to escape the period otherwise it means "any char" - - which just *happens* to match a period

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a regex fan, thats why I suggest the following solution, assuming your input is valid:

```
private static (string name, int x, int y) ParseText(string text)
    {
        var splitIndex = text.IndexOf(text.First(x => x >= '0' && x <= '9'));
        var name = text.Substring(0, splitIndex);
        var position = text.Substring(splitIndex).Split('.').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        return (name, position[0], position[1]);
    }

    private static string[,] Create2DArray((string name, int x, int y)[] items)
    {
        var array = new string[items.Max(i => i.x) + 1, items.Max(i => i.y) + 1];
        foreach (var item in items)
            array[item.x, item.y] = item.name;
        return array;
    }
```

Then you can call these functions like this:

```
var files = new[] { "head1.0", "head4.1", "head2.3" };
var arr = Create2DArray(files.Select(ParseText).ToArray());
```